# How do I get Flask to serve my .js files?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am doing some coding with Python, Flask and .js files all with some HTML and CSS linked in as well. My problem is that I have a dropdown menu and a button that can hide and unhide password text but when running in Flask, this side of things is not working and I believe that it has something to do with the javascript. This function works perfectly when I am running the HTML file locally and not through flask, but I am completely lost as to where to go from here?

In terms of what I have done already is to ensure that my file structure is correct and that these .js files are within the static folder (where CSS stylesheets are being pulled from perfectly fine). My script tags where I link the .js files are all at the end of the body tag and do not sit within the head tag.

```
<script src="../static/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../static/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="../static/js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="../static/js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
```

This is the app file that I am using for Flask and the simple code used to run this if it helps?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def render_static():

    return render_template('splash_page.html')

@app.route("/account")

def account_page():

    return render_template('account.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Below you will find my HTML code used as a template in Flask, this is it before the changes suggested below -

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home Page</title>

    <link href="../static/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../static/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="top-bar">
  <div class="top-bar-left">
    <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
      <li class="menu-text">Premier League Pro</li>
      <li>
        <a href="/account">Account</a>
        <ul class="menu vertical">
          <li><a href="/my account">My Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Predictor</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Odds Calculator</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="top-bar-right">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="button">Search</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="columns large-3"></div>
    <div class="columns large-6">
        <br>
        <br>
        <form class="show-password">
          <label for="username">Your login</label>
          <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Username" id="username">
          <div class="password-wrapper">
            <label for="password">Your password</label>
            <input type="password" value="" placeholder="Enter Password" id="password" class="password">
            <button class="unmask" type="button" title="Mask/Unmask password to check content">Unmask</button>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <a class="button small" href="#">Sign In</a>
    <div class="columns large-3"></div>
</div> 

    <script src="../static/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

If it helps to mention I am using Foundation as a CSS to help edit and make my webpages look nice.

When using the methods suggested below in terms of changing the script tags I get an error in the browser as follows -

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'static'
```

Comment: Hi there, can you confirm the scripts have loaded without error? Check the bowser console for hints. More information is needed to help.

Comment: When using the original script tags from above the .js files are being loaded and no errors are occurring, which leads me to assume that they're being loaded correctly. Using the suggested script tags has led to them not being linked to the HTML source code file, and thus meaning flask will not read them, I am now at this point lost.

Answer (score 1):

you should link your js files using this:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/vendor/jquery.js') }}"></script>
```

do this for all js files.
Hope that helps. If you still have any problem, please let me know.

for further investigation enable flask debug mode
To enable debug mode you can export the FLASK_DEBUG environment variable before running the server:

```
$ export FLASK_DEBUG=1
$ flask run
```

this will show you more detailed errors and stack traces in the browser.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I have just tried this and my files no longer come up as attached in Dreamweaver and when I booted up Flask I got an internal server error and what looks like it cannot now load the .js files at all. Any further ideas, I am lost?

Comment: enable debug mode in flask to show the traceback browser when there is an error.

Comment: Upon enabling debug mode it has now shown a collection of errors in the browser and they're as follows - jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'static'

Comment: update your question with html code and the errors shows in the browser , please

Comment: great, you must missed something from my code, try my code again and paste the updated html file that cause the jinja errors. maybe you missed (') or (,) or something else. double check and paste the updated html as my suggested code

Comment: heya buddy, I have done that now and ensured that it is exactly the same as what you have posted and still no luck, and the same errors are occurring. I have also tried this on my desktop to see if the problem was machine-based but unfortunately not.

Comment: i'm afraid i need exact code you use and exact errors you got, to assist you further. your code not updated to reflect the error you get. also errors are incomplete , there must be a template name , and line number displayed too.

Answer (score -2):

Jinja2 is a modern and designer-friendly templating language for Python. https://jinja2docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/
Try surrounding the script tag in your template with these two Jinja2 syntactic structures below:

```
{% block javascript %}
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/vendor/jquery.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

I vaguely recall Flask serving Javascript without this block once, but that was with Python 2.7. Maybe it's a bug.

It's probably a security feature to prevent XSS.